# Cannot get subprocess to end/exit

Tags: python, audio, subprocess

I am using the `subprocess` module to execute the `mimic` program (specified [here](https://github.com/MycroftAI/mimic1-core)). The code below successfully reads in some text and writes an mp3 file.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['mimic','-t','Hello','-o','hello.mp3'])

proc.stdin.close()
proc.wait()
```

However, the process never ends/exits, but rather just hangs. If it makes a difference, I will ultimately be putting this into a loop to read multiple texts and write multiple mp3 files. What do I need to add so the process exits?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe kill or terminate it after loop is done.

```py
proc.kill()
```

or

```py
proc.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to also specify `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`, like so:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['mimic','-t','Hello','-o','hello.mp3'],
stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

proc.stdin.close()
proc.wait()
```